# How can custom activity in azure data factory pipeline respond to pause and resume commands

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can custom activity in azure data factory respond to pause and resume commands of pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding so far, if custom activity or for that matter other activities gets started then pipeline pausing/stopping would take effect only after current activities finish running. Please advice if otherwise.